# Overwrite assignment operator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Ok so I've come to far so many problems with JavaScript `Number` and C#'s `decimal` not being particularly great with one another, so I decided to make a more sophisticated intermediate gimmick as so:

```
class Decimal {
    constructor(value, decimalPlaces = 2) {
        this.value = value;
        this.decimalPlaces = decimalPlaces;
    }

    valueOf() {
        let pow = Math.pow(10, this.decimalPlaces);
        let retv = Math.round(this.value * pow) / pow;
        return retv;
    }

    toString() {
        return this.value.toFixed(this.decimalPlaces);
    }

    toJSON() {
      return this.valueOf();
    }
}
```

So that I could

`let price = new Decimal(200 - 199.99, 2)`

And it works fine, even when serializing:

`let foo = { price: price; }`

this will serialize to

`{ price: 0.01 }`

as expected.

**THE PROBLEM HERE IS**

If we do `price = 10` or `price = someNumberVariable` we lose the almighty rounding powers of this class because now price is of type Number.

**The question is**

Is it possible to overwrite the assignment operator, so that `price = someNumberValue;` on user code actually does `price.value = someNumberValue` under the hood, to keep that auto-rounding magic going on?
Or even better, is there any native javascript stuff that does what I intend to in a much easier way that I might happen to not know of?

Comment: Why don't you just use regular numbers, and use `.toFixed(2)` when you're outputting it?

Comment: Because `toFixed(2)` would return `0.19` when converting `0.1999999` to 2 decimal places, I'd expect it to really round up to `0.2` which is a more correct value. This kind of small details really crack on when it comes to monetary values and customers will bother me to hell because of that 1 cent that supposedly went missing.

Comment: I don't have the exact solution to your problem, but it feels like you should be able to find it using [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Comment: Why not add an ```assignValue``` method to your class and use that to convert your ```Number``` to ```Decimal```?

Comment: @JonathanRys OP wants the user to be able to use `price = someNumberValue`, just for aesthetics reasons i guess

Comment: `0.1999999.toFixed(2)` returns `"0.20"`

Comment: I see, just checked it out, it's nice to know, I always thought it just runcated the value instead of rounding it.